# typedef char array as function parameter

Tags: c, function, typedef

C newbie here.
I wrote:

```
typedef unsigned char HBLOCK[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
typedef unsigned char HPRINTABLE[sizeof(HBLOCK)*2];
typedef struct {
                HBLOCK Primary;
                HBLOCK *Part;
               } FILE_HASH_MAP;
void blockhex(const HBLOCK *, HPRINTABLE *);
```

intending to write the function to convert HBLOCK to hex string. However when I tried to test if individual characters are assignable

```
void blockhex(const HBLOCK *block, HPRINTABLE *printable)
{
 printable[0]="6";
};
```

The compiler said

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘HPRINTABLE’ from type ‘char *’.
```

This puzzles me as I hoped the HPRINTABLE typedef would clearly indicate it to be an array type.
Moreover, when I call it like this

```
FILE_HASH_MAP fhm;
HPRINTABLE prt;
blockhex(fhm.Primary,&prt);
```

The compiler also says

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘blockhex’ from incompatible pointer type
```

and

```
note: expected ‘const unsigned char (*)[64]’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned char *’
```

those are not errors, of course, but I'd like to know what I did wrong anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void blockhex(const HBLOCK *block, HPRINTABLE *printable)
{
  printable[0]="6";
```

`printable[0]` is a `char`-array with `sizeof(HBLOCK)*2` elements. `"6"` is a `char`-array as well (with 2 elements, that is `'6'` and `'\0'`).

In C arrays cannot be assigend.

To copy arrays in general use [`memcpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html).

```
memcpy(printable[0], "6", sizeof "6"); /* Note that sizeof "6" evaluates to 2,
                                          because of the `0`-terminator each 
                                          C-"string" carries. */
```

To copy a C-"string" it better/easier to use [`strcpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) instead, like:

```
strcpy(printable[0], "6");
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
printable[0][0] = '6';
printable[0][1] = '\0';
```

More on how to handle "strings" in C is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling

---

To have `printable` being a `char`-array declare it as `HPRINTABLE printable` and do not use the address-of operator `&` on `prt` when calling `blockhex();`.

Same for `block`.

Comment: I know arrays cannot be assigned. Can individual array elements be assigned? What's wrong with printable[0]="6"; ?

Comment: So why do you try then and wonder the compiler complains? @Barvinok

Comment: I thought a single character is a single charater, not an array. Is strcpy() the only way to assign an individual array element?

Comment: @Barvinok `"6"` is an array . (It has 2 elements: `'6'` and `'\0'`). Arrays cannot be assigned.

Comment: @Barvinok: `'6'` would be a single `char`. Note quotes.

Comment: I still don't get it :( filemap.c:53:14: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘HPRINTABLE’ from type ‘int’
  printable[0]='6';

Comment: @Barvinok: You cannot assign a `char` to a `char`-array. Please read my answer closely.

Comment: How come printable[0] is an array?? How do I then address individual elements of a variable of type HPRINTABLE ?

Comment: Please note that `printable` is a **pointer** to `HPRINTABLE` not a `HPRINTABLE` itself.  @Barvinok So doing `printable[0]` you get the `HPRINTABLE`.

Comment: @alk I am desperately trying to understand but failing. When you write "printable[0] is a char-array with sizeof(HBLOCK)*2 elements" I don't understand how this come to be when my intention was to typedef an array type and be able to assign its individual elements such as [0], [1] etc. It's not about the strings anymore, it's something fundamental with typedefs that I don't get. Please help.

Comment: @Barvinok: To have `printable` being a `char`-array declare it as `HPRINTABLE  printable` and do not use the address-of operator `&` on `prt` when calling `blockhex();`.